# How can I order by two same attributes from differents tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got this DB. For starters, I didn't created this DB and I can't change the structure, so I have to deal with it.

```
+------+  +--------+  +--------+
| FORM |  | FORM_A |  | FORM_B |
+------+  +--------+  +--------+
| id   |  | form_id|  | form_id|
          | name   |  | name   |
```

I'm not an Oracle user, I need to get all the FORM where I will get FORM_A datas as well as FORM_B, but I need to order it by name from both tables. "name" is the same kind of datas from FORM_A and FORM_B, too bad it's not in FORM.

```
Exemple :
FORM_A = [a, b, d, f]
FORM_B = [e, c, g]
FORM datas must be ordered as FORM_A(a), FORM_A(b), FORM_B(c), FORM_A(d), FORM_B(e)...
```

At first I think I'll have to order it manually with some loops, but I wonder if there is a way to order from multiples tables together, and not one after the other ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the following table contents:

```
      FORM               FORM_A              FORM_B
 +----+--------+  +------+---------+  +------+---------+
 | ID | NAME   |  | NAME | FORM_ID |  | NAME | FORM_ID |
 +----+--------+  |+-----+---------+  |+-----+---------+
 |  1 | First  |  | a    |       1 |  | e    |       3 |
 |  2 | Second |  | b    |       2 |  | c    |       4 |
 |  3 | Third  |  | d    |       2 |  | g    |       5 |
 |  4 | Fourth |  | f    |       3 |  +------+---------+
 |  5 | Fifth  |  +------+---------+
 +----+--------+
```

You can use `UNION` to select from two tables, provided that the two tables have the same column structure:

```
SELECT FORM_A.form_id, FORM_A.name
FROM FORM_A 
UNION ALL 
SELECT FORM_B.form_id, FORM_B.name 
FROM FORM_B
ORDER BY name;

   FORM_ID NAME
---------- -----
         1 a
         2 b
         4 c
         2 d
         3 e
         3 f
         5 g
```

By joining the `FORM_ID` with the `FORM` table, you then get the corresponding rows from `FORM`:

```
SELECT ab.Name AS AB, f.Name AS DATA
FROM (SELECT FORM_A.form_id, FORM_A.name
      FROM FORM_A
      UNION ALL
      SELECT FORM_B.form_id , FORM_B.name
      FROM FORM_B
      ORDER BY name) ab
      JOIN FORM f ON f.id=ab.FORM_ID;

AB    DATA
----- ----------
a     First
b     Second
c     Fourth
d     Second
e     Third
f     Third
g     Fifth
```

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
select * 
      from ( select id, null as name from form union all
             select id, name from formA union all
             select id, name from formB 
            ) temp
      order by temp.name
```